# How do I pass configurations to index.html in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to pass google tag manager id based on the environment to my script in `index.html` in my vue app but I can't find a way to pass configs to a html file. Kindly assist.

Here is the script

```
<script>
  (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({ "gtm.start": new Date().getTime(), event: "gtm.js" });
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j = d.createElement(s),
      dl = l != "dataLayer" ? "&l=" + l : "";
    j.async = true;
    j.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=" + i + dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
  })(window, document, "script", "dataLayer", "<env-gtm-id-goes-here>"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `html interpolation`. [Refer here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#interpolation)

In combination with the vue `Environment Variables`. [Refer Here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)

For example:
make a new file name `.env` and make entry
`VUE_APP_ENVARS=prod` and use it inside your `index.html` with the html interpolation

`<p>The username to test is <%= VUE_APP_ENVIR %></p>`

**Update:** Since you need to access this variable in the `<script>` tag, use this

> (window, document, "script", "dataLayer", "<%= VUE_APP_ENVIR %>"